# Rust "extern mod std;" fails with "multiple matching crates for `core`"

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

I started the Rust for Rubyists tutorial and this code has tripped me up:

```
extern mod std;

#[test]
fn this_tests_code() {
    println("")
}

fn main() {}
```

Attempting to compile this gives me:

```
> rustc testing.rs
testing.rs:1:0: 1:0 error: multiple matching crates for `core`
testing.rs:1 extern mod std;
             ^
note: candidates:
note: path: /usr/local/lib/rustc/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-c3ca5d77d81b46c1-0.5.dylib
note: meta: name = "core"
note: meta: vers = "0.5"
note: meta: uuid = "c70c24a7-5551-4f73-8e37-380b11d80be8"
note: meta: url = "https://github.com/mozilla/rust/tree/master/src/libcore"
note: path: /usr/local/lib/rustc/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-c3ca5d77d81b46c1-0.6.dylib
note: meta: name = "core"
note: meta: vers = "0.6"
note: meta: uuid = "c70c24a7-5551-4f73-8e37-380b11d80be8"
note: meta: url = "https://github.com/mozilla/rust/tree/master/src/libcore"
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm using rustc 0.6. I'm not sure what it's supposed to be doing, so can anyone give me some insights?

Comment: Did you try going to `/usr/local/lib/rustc/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-c3ca5d77d81b46c1-0.5.dylib`, and deleting it (or just renaming it)?

Comment: @RamonSnir is correct, you should delete all the `...-0.5.dylib` files in that directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have two versions of libstd installed, 0.5 and 0.6. You should either delete the older one at:

```
/usr/local/lib/rustc/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-c3ca5d77d81b46c1-0.5.dylib
```

or be more specific to rust about which library you want to link:

```
extern mod std (vers = "0.6");
```